# How to generate raster pattern with Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I wonder if there is a way to generate pixmaps similar to avatars seen here.
The procedurally generated pixmaps then could be saved locally (for instance as *.png)  to be latter picked by QLabels.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        label=QtGui.QLabel()
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.layout().addWidget(label)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what's your question exactly?

Comment: Can you try to be a little less blatant when begging someone to write your code for you? What efforts have you made to solve your own problem?

Comment: I've seen something close to it while digging to Flask.